# List the customer ID of customer who have placed more than one order in DBMS

Tags: oracle

List the customer ID of customer who have placed more than one order in DBMS

```sql
Select count (custid) as "number of orders more than one"
from orders
where order date is less than 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GROUP BY in conjunction with a HAVING clause:

```sql
SELECT CustomerId, Count(*) AS NumberOfOrders
FROM Order
WHERE OrderDate < 1
GROUP BY CustomerId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The WHERE clause is applied before grouping. The HAVING clause is applied after grouping and is used when you need to apply constraints on values returned by aggregate functions.

I am not sure what *"order date is less than 1;"* means, but this condition must be placed in the WHERE clause.

If by *"number of orders more than one"* you mean number of orders exceeding 1, you can write `Count(*) - 1 AS NumberOfOrdersExceedingOne` (as @Bohemian pointed out) in conjunction with `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`.

Comment: You said *HAVING clause ... can contain aggregate functions* suggesting that it can contain other types of values too: `HAVING` can *only* refer to aggregated values and constants. Also, I suspect OP's request for *number of orders more than one* could mean `COUNT(*) - 1`